# Как определить несколько типов для rest parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript.
Есть некоторый класс.
Метод `something(...)` может принимать несколько аргументов, и это известно до создания экземпляра.

```
// Тип "T" должен описать последовательность типов метода something
class Foo<T> {

  #callback: (...args: T[]) => void

  constructor(callback: (...args: T[]) => void) {
    this.#callback = callback
  }

  // Как быть с параметрами (a: number, b:string)
  something(...args: T[]): void {
    this.#callback(...args)
  }
}

// Здесь уже известно какие параметры будет принимать метод `Foo.something(...)`,
// и соответственно какие получит `callback`.
const callback = (a: number, b: string): void => {
  // ...
}

// Это разумеется не сработает, даже callback не будет соответствовать ожидаемому типу
const cfoo = new Foo<(number | string)>(callback)
cfoo.something(123, 'str')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEiIQQOEEfhBQIgCp1IFhBB8IIbhBBsIIVhBC8IKGtJIIIggDCCBCIIDIgo0aJGO6gTCCU4ZV73WgUxrNQgHhAcFNCjKgAzgHsAtgFMALgAsAlgDsA5gCgAxgBsAhlKmgAYjJkAeBAD5QAbx07QoAMR6jBgwCMjegDWAFygABQAdFFGAE5aUqEIANoAugCUoAC8DgBuMmoAJi5uejIaUkoxAK56SjIxYV4+-kGhkdFxCaDJ6Vm5+QUZzm5uqmpSEZ7efgGBWaBNM0GuoAC+xaAgoIBYIGSAXCCggIwggNIgPCS0ZIACIGQiFNdCkOFGoRpVcr4KMQA0oL7BFTFNFo0itZIoxtp2hFYvFEqk0qE8oUnCtRuoJlNmrMoTCpCC3Ot1jotoB0EBQOBINEAwiC4UCQQDsIMwKRQuKA9vtIDgLvdRJdjkcqeSKLRLpA8JAhJQaLdxKAAAaWGQRMHKdSQqIRNJyr7EsCPEhoNAUJkUEjG-Cs9l7Tm0TBUwDiIJBhXLFi1AnKIvoyhUFtM3fMws9QK93p8fn9pJUgQjQEiCn0UW4thqdEStoBaEDEoGu9KpIlEJEA8iCgPBckjXQ5GsiiH4SWmu2YlrmHQWiUAGo0ms3MARSwhYSASHBCNBCKm8GBUr3lJQLABmVnmGgUAHcLFZrGEQx8YqAAD6RwHaNJ2Rp+2YgvQLpUqiFaMIARgATABmH4AcgB77SQA)

Возможно ли в rest parameters определить несколько типов, соблюдая установленную последовательность?

Comment: *"Тип "T" должен описать последовательность типов метода something"* - что вы под этим подразумеваете? Что значит последовательность типов метода?

Comment: @smellyshovel Я подразумевал последовательность передачи аргументов с разными типами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось это делается с помощью кортежей.
Тип кортежа описывается как:

```
T extends any[]
```

Вот так все работает:

```
class Foo<T extends any[]> {

  #callback: (...args: T) => void

  constructor(callback: (...args: T) => void) {
    this.#callback = callback
  }

  something(...args: T): void {
    this.#callback(...args)
  }
}

const callback = (a?: number, b?: string): void => {
  // ...
}

const cfoo = new Foo<[number?, string?]>(callback)
cfoo.something(123, 'str')
cfoo.something('error string', 'str')
// -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^ - error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVaBTAHgF3QOwBMYw8BPAbQF0A+aAbwCgHpoBiYMEEAIzGAGsAXNAAUAOglgATgHMIwlAEpoAXloA3eAEsCTFsHh4I2KQFdg2eFJEcuvAcPGTZ86EtUbtBZYxYtsABZaEGLsnDx8-KrQthECzNAAvnrQEPAAtuiBWngyTmLScgqKwpo69An+QSFhdpH5hRCKCcnJDAZG2DHh9lEqomAA-MJ4punc6FIANNDcw6kmOTIl0GUEHhUsAPRb0BJiDG0dxjEAZojReOgA7nCISOSj45ODM8ZSS4M0Nj2RzcDneBiNKZbK5EQARgATABmGYAcne8P+gOBGSyQXB8MmUisCw+uXhCKRzR20AAtJSqdSqQA9ekMxn0ikYKS4qRAA)